# how to construct pattern in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

How to generate a regular expression that will scan a full text file (say, sample.txt) and return the index of the first occurance of STRT followed by any number of spaces and then `a`. That means it can be like

```
"STRT   ."
```

or it can be like

```
"STRT        ."
```

Comment: Must resist snarky comment...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `@"STRT\s*\."`

the \s* will match any number of whitespace characters and . will match the literal period.

Comment: You forgot to escape the dot. Currently it will match almost everything after the white space.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - strange. I would assume the '\' character is some kind of escape in markdown, but the \s was maintained.  Thanks for the correction.